# Google app engine sql connection with python

Tags: python, sql-server, google-app-engine

Im making a webpage through google app engine that querys based on the person needs from an existing SQL database located on a local server. Im having trouble importing third party python libraries because most of them are not written in native python code (google app engine only supports fully python code). I have searched everywere for a way to connect to this database but I cant find a way around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) library, which is a built-in library for App Engine. See the [set up instructions in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Setting_up) for details.

Specify the MySQLdb library in the `app.yaml` libraries element:

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

Answer (score 0):

What @BrettJ said, some of the common third-party libs for python are not pure python, and thus cannot be imported into the project unless google whitelists them end enables them to be imported in a safe manner, basically, what you need to do is to have MySQLdb library set in the app.yaml file.

```
    libraries:
      - name: MySQLdb
      version: "latest"
```

I highly suggest you go through several tutorials, this is basic stuff and will be cleared to you in minimum time.